# Create ordered json string to use for key signing

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dictionary, data-structures

To understand the problem I need to provide some background to what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to create a JWT with this [library](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT) that will be signed with a private key.

My problem is that the dictionary that I use to create the JSON is unordered, which therefore results in an unordered JSON string.

The code below prints the JSON string in any order.

```
let dictionary = ["aKey": "aValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"]

    if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: dictionary,
      options: .prettyPrinted
      ),
      let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                               encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
          print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
    }
let privateKey = theJSONText.data(using: .utf8)
let jwtSigner = JWTSigner.hs256(privateKey: privateKey)
let signedJWT = try myJWT.sign(using: jwtSigner) // This produces a JWT with an invalid signature
```

The result of this is that my JWT produces an invalid signature. How do I produce a JSON string that has order?

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition so the order doesn't matter. However you should delete the  `prettyPrinted` option which adds unnecessary whitespace characters. The server doesn't care about human readability at all. And `privateKey` is an optional, this could also be an issue. Create the data with non-optional `let privateKey = Data(theJSONText.utf8)`

Comment: The order does matter because I need my JSON string to be in this exact order `"{"aKey": "aValue", "anotherKey": "anotherValue"}"` otherwise the `privateKey` data is invalid

Comment: Are you sure that the dictionary order causes your issue?

Comment: I'm sure, it's the dictionary that creates the string after all, if the dictionary is unordered so is the string

Answer (score 0):

`JSONEncoder` encodes a dictionary always in the same order (which however might **not** be the given *order* of the dictionary). But maybe it fulfills your needs.

```
if let theJSONData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary) {
    let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")
}
```

And there is also the `sortedKeys` option of `OutputFormatting`

And – once again – **never** *prettyPrint* anything which is going to be sent to a server.

Comment: I understand about the _prettyprinting_, I only use that for debugging purposes. The issue isn't solved using a JSONEncoder as the dictionary may still be in the wrong order. Notice how the `print` statement produces a different string each time.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `sortedKeys` option? If it doesn’t work either you have to build the JSON string *manually*.

Comment: Yes I have done. Building the JSON string manually doesn't work either as getting the string data from `JSONSerialization` produces bytes from a string and not from JSON.

Comment: JSON **is** a string. You can build a JSON string with string interpolation and convert it to `Data` (without JSONSerialization).

Comment: I've tried adding this as a string and converting it to `.utf8` data: `"{"aKey":"aValue",anotherKey": "anotherValue"}"` but the JWT signature is still invalid. I think it may be due to escape characters included when the string is converted to `Data`

Comment: In your example there are no escaped characters. I still believe that the dictionary order is irrelevant and the issue lies somewhere else.